# How to Use sas macro to sampling multiple datasets

Tags: sas, sampling, sas-macro

I have several datasets with the same structure(two variables:"code" and "group") while different in dataset name(with no rule). 
Now I have to do simple random sampling in these datasets, the method is selcet one observation from each "group" randomly.
I know how to write the basic programme:

```
data sample; 
set original;
where group=‘group_value’;
run;
proc surveyselect data=sample method=srs n=1 seed=821 out=fsample; 
run;
```

I want to process these datasets more efficiently but I know little about sas macro, anyone can give me some advice on using sas macro to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better with PROC SURVEYSELECT is the STRATA option.

```
data have;
 do group = 1 to 5;
  do x = 1 to 5;
    output;
  end;
 end;
run;

proc surveyselect data=have n=1 out=want;
 strata group;
run;
```

`STRATA` will as for a sample of `n` items per unique value of the `strata` variable.  (Also works on percents.)  Also requires sorting (because it works more or less like `by`).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've read sas's documents of proc surveyselect several times and mistaken the "n" for the total sample size instead of each level's sample size. What a shame.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you do not need a big macro loop, using a PROC with a BY statement is much more efficient.  Suggest:

```
proc surveyselect data=original method=srs ... ;
  by group ;
run ;
```

(sort by group first if unsorted)

Comment: thanks,I just make things complicated.I haven't realized I can use by statement in proc surverselect